# Call didReceiveApplicationContext while device is asleep?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification, apple-watch, wcsession

When I click a button in my apple watch app, I want to cancel a local notification that was scheduled by the iPhone app.

Right now, I'm sending information using the updateApplicationContext method to transfer info between the watch and the phone, and I cancel my local notifications through the didReceiveApplicationContext method.

Right now, didReceiveApplicationContext only gets called when the app is open. That means that the notification still appears if I haven't opened the app in the meantime. I need to make sure the notification doesn't appear even if I don't open the app.

**Is there any way to call didReceiveApplicationContext in the background while the device is asleep or the app is not in the foreground?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for this you will have to check if the WatchKit extension's `WCSession`'s `reachable` property is `true`/`YES`, and if it is use the one of the `sendMessage` APIs as these can wake the iOS app up in the background.

Comment: Thank you so much!